# Cannot access value within React Redux Form component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I have a Page that takes text and submits to the back end using React, Redux Form, and React Bootstrap.

Page:

```
  <Form.Label className="text-muted">Social Media</Form.Label>
              <hr />
              <TextField
                type="text"
                label="Twitter"
                name="social_media.twitter"
                placeholder={"link to your twitter"}
                onChange={(e) => this.handleSocialMediaLinkChange(e, "twitter")}
                value={social_media && social_media.twitter}
              />
              <TextField
                type="text"
                label="Reddit"
                name="social_media.reddit"
                placeholder={"link to your reddit"}
                onChange={(e) => this.handleSocialMediaLinkChange(e, "reddit")}
                value={
                 social_media && social_media.reddit|| "NO VALUE"
                }
              />
```

TextField Component:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Field as FormField } from "redux-form";
import { Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import "../../App.css";

const renderTextField = ({
  label,
  type,
  input,
  classes,
  disabled,
  onChange,
  placeholder,
  accept,
  id,
  meta: { touched, invalid, error },
  ...props
}) => {
    return (
      <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
        <Form.Label>{label}</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          type={type}
          {...input}
          className={classes}
          disabled={disabled}
          {...props}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          accept={accept}
        />
        {touched && invalid && <div className="signerror">{error}</div>}
      </Form.Group>
    );
};

const Field = (props) => (
  <FormField autoComplete={props.name} value={props.value} {...props} />
);

Field.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.string,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  label: PropTypes.string,
  type: PropTypes.string,
  disabled: PropTypes.any,
  value: PropTypes.any,
  id: PropTypes.string,
  onChange: PropTypes.func,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string,
  accept: PropTypes.any,
};

Field.defaultProps = {
  component: renderTextField,
};

export default Field;
```

This is where the issue lies - in the textfield component - but I'm not sure why or whats going on.

### The issue:

The state for `social_media.reddit && social_media.twitter` is twitter has a valid value, and reddit is undefined.

When the page loads - it properly shows `"twitter.com"` and `"undefined"` **BUT** when doing the check on the undefined value and returning something else - NOTHING WILL CHANGE. It will always show whatever the first value is. It doesn't update.

So, after some debugging I found out that the `value` field/prop inside TextField is "undefined" always.

Notice how its missing a `value={value}` field in the *renderTextField* component.

I've changed the component to this to add a value field:

```
const renderTextField = ({
  label,
  type,
  input,
  classes,
  disabled,
  onChange,
  placeholder,
  value,
  accept,
  id,
  meta: { touched, invalid, error },
  ...props
}) => {
    return (
      <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
        <Form.Label>{label}</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          type={type}
          {...input}
          className={classes}
          disabled={disabled}
          {...props}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          accept={accept}
          value={value}
        />
        {touched && invalid && <div className="signerror">{error}</div>}
      </Form.Group>
    );
};

const Field = (props) => (
  <FormField autoComplete={props.name} value={props.value} {...props} />
);

Field.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.string,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  label: PropTypes.string,
  type: PropTypes.string,
  disabled: PropTypes.any,
  value: PropTypes.any,
  id: PropTypes.string,
  onChange: PropTypes.func,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string,
  accept: PropTypes.any,
};

Field.defaultProps = {
  component: renderTextField,
};

export default Field;
```

Now the field will never update with any values at all - it just remains blank on the UI.

So whats going on here and what am I missing?

TL;DR - Cannot access the value property in the textfield. Displays undefined or nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Per the React Bootstrap documentation (towards the bottom), it looks like if you add value prop on the Form.Control you'll also need an onChange
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/

Also, in your page component did you intend to group booleans as such:

```
value={(social_media && social_media.reddit) || "NO VALUE" }
```

Comment: I don't follow, I've included onChange in both the React UI side, and within the <TextField/> proptypes and pass it in. Also when updating with the "NO VALUE" code it still returns undefined in the text box. Thats the issue I've been dealing with. When console.logging the props in TextField component it only shows "autocomplete" and nothing else. This is probably the issue, but even though I include value or onChange, it doesn't show it as a prop being received.

Finally, I think its more of a redux form issue and not Bootstrap (FormField isn't in bootstrap)